# Index was outside the bounds of the array - integers

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, indexing

I have just run across a problem which is common but I'm not sure why it's happening in this instance.

```
string s;
int c1, c2, c3, c4;    

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String number;
    s = textBox1.Text;
    int[] d = s.Select(c => (int)c - (int)'0').ToArray();

    try
    {
        c1 = (4 * d[1] + 10 * d[2] + 9 * d[3] + 2 * d[4] + d[5] + 7 * d[6]) % 11;
        c2 = (7 * d[1] + 8 * d[2] + 7 * d[3] + d[4] + 9 * d[5] + 6 * d[6]) % 11;
        c3 = (9 * d[1] + d[2] + 7 * d[3] + 8 * d[4] + 7 * d[5] + 7 * d[6]) % 11;
        c4 = (d[1] + 2 * d[2] + 9 * d[3] + 10 * d[4] + 4 * d[5] + d[6]) % 11;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    number = d[1]+d[2]+d[3]+d[4]+d[5]+d[6]+c1+c2+c3+c4.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = number;    
}
```

It will accept the number in the first `TextBox`(es) fine. As soon as it moves onto the catch section it will pop up with an error `Index was outside the bounds of the array` Is there something obvious I'm missing? or is this quite unique to my program?

Comment: Array indexing starts at 0, you're starting at 1. Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bellieve that you think your array goes from 1 to 6.
Its from 0 to 5.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that your `TextBox` contains *at least 6 characters* else it gives an exception:

```
if(textBox1.Text.Length >= 6)
{
   //your code here
}
else
   MessageBox.Show("You must insert at least 6 characters");
```

**And then remember that the index of the array starts from 0 not 1**.

Answer (score 1):

How many chars are in the input string `s = textBox1.Text;`? 
You don't perform any check on the user input.

For example

```
textBox1.Text = "1234"; // only 4 digits
```

then, when you try to use index 4/5/6 you get the error.
Of course, you should also consider that **arrays indexes start at zero** not at one.
In my input above, you will have only index from 0 to 3.

A simple check should be (Assuming you've already ruled out non-numeric data by other means)

```
s = textBox1.Text;
if(s.Length != 6)
    MessageBox.Show("6 digits required!");
else
    .......
```